# Powershell Access to the path denied

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, administrator, windows-server-2008-r2

I'm sure this has been asked a million times, but I can't figure out why I can't run this simple command in powershell:

```
PS> new-item -path c:\users\me\desktop\testfolder -name (get-date).txt -value (get-date).toString() -itemtype file
```

I am forever getting the following error:

```
New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\Me\desktop\testfolder' is denied.

... PermissionDenied: ... UnauthorizedAccessException
... FullyQualifiedErrorId: NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell...
```

Anyway,

I've tried ALL of the following, to no avail:

- Running powershell as Administrator (i.e, "Run as Administrator")
- Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
- "takeown" on the folder
- setting the security settings on the folder to: "everyone > full control"
- -FORCE

Where the heck should I go hunting for an answer next? I'm an administrator on my local machine. This is extremely frustrating not to have rights to do something as simple as creating a stupid text file...

Pulling hair-out...

Comment: Have you tried with the -Force parameter?

Comment: just tried, same error (i'll add that to my above list now)

Comment: Did some test on XP, can't create files or folders in user folders (in my case C:\Documents and Settings). I can perform this in C:\ however. Has to do something with ACLs or the like.

Answer (score 11):

The the DateTime string format returned by `Get-Date` contains characters that can't be used for file names. Try something like this:

```
new-item -path .\desktop\testfolder -name "$(get-date -format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmm').txt" `
        -value (get-date).toString() -itemtype file
```

Just change the format string to meet your needs.

Comment: Duh...good catch.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `-name (get-date).txt` is not the same as `(get-date) + ".txt"`. The former will try to read a property named "txt" on the returned `System.DateTime` object, and the latter will append the string ".txt" to a string representation of the date. In the former, .txt as a property returns `$null` because it does not exist. This, in turn, means you're trying to effectively run `new-item -path .\desktop\folder` which returns access denied because folder already exists.

Answer (score -1):

I also received this error due to the read-only flag. This can be fixed using:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path c:\users\me\desktop\testfolder -Name IsReadOnly -Value $true
```